# Can statutory rape charges be dismissed if the minor is now of age?

Tags: minor, court, rape

I am a 16-year old female in Michigan and I am going to have to testify against my ex-boyfriend in a statutory rape case. What happened was consensual and my parents are not pressing charges, the state is. Because I am of age now, is it possible for me to get the charges against him dismissed?

Comment: Get actual legal advice. "What happened was consensual" - colloquially speaking, it might have been, but legally speaking?

Comment: What will happen if you don't testify?  What will happen if you invoke the fifth amendment on the stand or claim that you don't remember?  A lawyer can help you answer these questions.  But your age at the time of the alleged crime is what matters, not your age at the time of the trial.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You can ask, but the prosecutor has the power to bring charges with or without your consent and is not required to drop the charged because you want them to be dropped.

In fact, prosecutors have with some regularity had judges incarcerate young women who refuse to testify in statutory rape cases after being subpoenaed to do so, until they agree to testify.